# How to call method from Hash?

Tags: ruby

It's a calculator program, and I would like to call + operation from Hash.

```
class Command
  def storeOperandA(a)
    puts "A:" + a.to_s
    @a = a
  end

  def storeOperandB(b)
    puts "B:" + b.to_s
    @b = b
  end

  def plusCommand
    result = @a + @b
    puts result
  end

  def minusCommand
    result = @a - @b
    puts result
  end

  def execute(operation)
    @operation = operation
    if operation == "+"
      self.plusCommand
    elsif operation == "-"
      self.minusCommand
    end
  end

  operations = { :+ => plusCommand }
end

calculator = Command.new
calculator.storeOperandA(4)
calculator.storeOperandB(3)
calculator.execute["+"]
```

It's a calculator program, and I would like to call + operation from Hash.

Comment: What part are you having issues with? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: calc.rb:24:in 'execute':wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
from calc.rb:44:in '(main)'

Comment: Have you tried `calculator.execute("+")` instead of `calculator.execute["+"]`? Note the rounded brackets instead of the square brackets.

Comment: now it says: http://oi59.tinypic.com/15s8mes.jpg

Comment: Because the `Command` class doesn't have a class method named `plusCommand`.

Comment: now it says...: http://oi59.tinypic.com/4lg1mv.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
class Command
  def storeOperandA(a)
    puts "A:" + a.to_s
    @a = a
  end

  def storeOperandB(b)
    puts "B:" + b.to_s
    @b = b
  end

  def plusCommand
    result = @a + @b
    puts result
  end

  def minusCommand
    result = @a - @b
    puts result
  end

  def execute(oper)
    send OPERATIONS[oper.to_sym]
  end

  OPERATIONS = { :+ => :plusCommand }

end

calculator = Command.new
calculator.storeOperandA(4)
calculator.storeOperandB(3)
calculator.execute("+")

#=> 
A:4
B:3
7
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1, one suggestion: You didn't have to create another constant `OPERATIONS` instead `def execute(oper) send { :+ => :plusCommand }[oper.to_sym] end`. Two reasons: 1 - constants can be modified in runtime. 2 - Constants occupies memory during runtime where as methods don't, and instance of hash will be destroyed once context is out of the method where as constant won't.